# Remove cycles from digraph without losing information (aka howto 'dagify' a digraph)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, markov-chains, random-walk, directed-graphs

Given a digraph (directed graph) $G = (V, E)$, i'm looking for simply and reasonable ways of transforming $G$ into a DAG (directed acyclic graph) without "losing information".

One way of doing this is perhaps to partition $G$ into strongly connected components and consider the DAG induced on components (in a natural way...). I don't like this (for example, it would require the heavy-duty computation of the strongly connected components).

I've come up with something which goes a follows. For a positive integer $L$, define the digraph $G^{(L)} = (V, E^{(L)})$ by

$$E^{(L)} = \{(x, y) \in V^2 | \exists \text{ a path }x \rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow y \text{ of length } \ge L \}.
$$
Thus $(x, y) \in E^{(L)}$ iff it is possible to go from $x$ to $y$ in $L$ or more steps. In particular, $G^{(1)} = \bar{G}$, the [transitive closure](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermeture_transitive#Th%C3%A9orie_des_graphes) of $G$, defined by saying $(x, y)$ is an edge of $\bar{G}$ iff there is a directed path from $x$ and $y$ in $G$.

Finally, define $l(G) = \inf \{L | G^{(L)}\text{ is a DAG}\}$ and $G^{(*)} := G^{(l(G))}$, the 'dagification' of $G$.

Now, for simplicity, assume that the set of nodes $V$ is finite. The following observations are immediate:

- $l(G)$ is always finite (in fact $l(G) \le |V|^2$)
- $G \subseteq G^{(1)} \supseteq G^{(2)} \supseteq \ldots \supseteq G^{(l(G))}$
- If $G = C_n$ is the directed cycle on $n$ nodes, then $l(G) = n$ and $G^{(*)} = \emptyset$.

Are there other interesting things which can be said ? For example,

- when do we have $l(G) = 1$ ? Or equivalently, when is $\bar{G}$ a DAG ?
- Can we (tightly) bound $l(G)$ in terms of $|V|$ and $|E|$ for a reasonably large / interesting family of digraphs ?
- Is there a simple relationship between $G$ and $G^{(*)}$.
- Is $G^{(*)}$ (conceptually) similar to any known objects in domain of markov chains ?

## What do i mean by "information loss" ?

Well, I've not yet been able to precisely formulate what I mean by "information loss" in a reasonable way. However, I'll remark that squashing $C_n$ to $\emptyset$ is no loss of information since $C_n$ really contains no information except for the number $n$. Ultimately, for any digraph $G$, I'd want to transform it to a DAG in which cycles are shrunk to $\emptyset$, connected components are shrunk to single points, etc. As you see, it's not really yet clear in my mind... I hope to make this clearer very soon.

Comment: What do you mean, without “losing information”? both methods of “dagifying” these graphs you describe seem to lose most of the information in the graphs.

Comment: Are you looking for a bijection (up to isomorphism) between directed graphs and DAGS?

Comment: Why is $G^{(1)} = G$ for an acyclic graph? It seems like $G^{(1)}$ is instead the transitive closure: e.g., if $G$ is a directed path on $n$ vertices, than $G^{(1)}$ is a transitive tournament on $n$ vertices.

Comment: @MishaLavrov you're right. I just noticed the bug too and was just about to correct it. Thanks! I hastily did the computation on my palm. Indeed $G^{(1)}$  is the transitive closure of $G$, i.e $(x, y)$ is an edge of $G^{(1)}$ iff there is a directed path from $x$ to $y$ in $G$. Fixing.

Comment: @SeanEnglish I'm having a hard time formalizing what I precisely mean by "information loss". However, I'll remark that squashing $C_n$ to $\emptyset$ is no loss of information since $C_n$ really contains no information except for the number $n$. Ultimately, for any $G$ I'd want to transform it to a DAG in which cycles are shrunk to $\emptyset$, connected components are shrunk to single points, etc.  As you see, it's not really yet clear in my mind... I hope to make this clearer very soon.

Comment: Collapse strongly connected components to points. You will get a directed tree.

Comment: Let $G$ be the disjoint union of a directed cycle and a directed path. Does your $G^{(*)}$ do what you want? It seems the path only survives if it is longer than the cycle.

Comment: Are you trying to create a spanning tree?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991823/finding-a-minimum-spanning-tree-on-a-directed-graph

Comment: What do you mean by "*the heavy-duty computation of the strongly connected components*"?! Strongly connected components can be found in linear time: anything less heavy-duty doesn't process the entire graph.

Answer (score 2):

I think I can answer the first two parts of your question.

$l(G)=1$ if and only if $G$ is acyclic. Indeed, as you mentioned $G^{(1)}$ is the transitive closure of $G$. Strongly connected components in $G$ correspond to complete subgraphs in the transitive closure, so $G$ is acyclic if and only if the transitive closure of $G$ is acyclic.

For a relationship between $G^{L}$ and $G^{L+1}$, the best I’ve got is that $G^{L+1}$ is a subgraph of $G^{L}$. Indeed, if a path of length $\geq L+1$ exists between teo vertices, than surely a path of length $\geq L$ exists. I’m not sure this could be considered “nice” though.

You mention in your question that $l(G)\leq n^2$(where $n$ is the order of your graph), but it seems that we can get $l(G)\leq n$ since a path that uses every vertex is length $n-1$, and thus we do not have longer paths. Thus $G^{(n)}$ is empty for any digraph $G$ on $n$ vertices.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the useful remarks. Also, yes indeed $G \subseteq G^{(1)} \supseteq G^{(2)} \supseteq \ldots \supseteq G^{(l(G))}$. I failed to note that in my list of 'immediate facts'. Thanks for pointing it out though.